# Why is My Mesh Black?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

For some reason my mesh is black whenever I go into weight paint mode, and the colors that appear when I weight paint are red. I want to change it to blue (the mesh)

[image]

Comment: hello, it must be something in your display settings, could you please share your file?  https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Set the Weight to 0 then try again.